Upload file in omniscript
I am trying to save a file using content document link. I have used post data raptor and map the fields. My file is also getting uploaded in the related object's file. But I am getting this error after my data raptor post is launch which saves the file. below is the error.
Cannot invoke "java.util.List.get(int)" because the return value of "java.util.Map.get(Object)" is null

